# How to represent maps in OWL?

Tags: owl

This is a simplified extract from my ontology:

```xml
    <owl:Class rdf:ID="Role" />
    <owl:Class rdf:ID="Location" />
    <owl:Class rdf:ID="SalaryRange">
      <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#HasLocation" />
    </owl:Class>
    <owl:Class rdf:ID="HasLocation" />
    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="location">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#HasLocation" />
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Location" />
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    <owl:DataProperty rdf:ID="salaryRangeOfRole">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Role" />
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#SalaryRange" />
    </owl:DataProperty>
```

How can I ensure now that the `Location`s in the `SalaryRange`s are unique per `Role`?

I have read about `FunctionalProperty`s, but do not see how to use this in this case.

Comment: I think you have to define "local functionality" which is modeled via class expressions. Can you give an example of the instance data please? I didn't get how your classes are "connected" now. A role has a salary range with a location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge you have here is that you basically want a unique constraint on `Role` and `Location` for `SalaryRange`. Funtional properties really is defined for a single property - except if you do model some functional property through class expressions.

A simple way to achieve this (if you are using OWL) is through key constraints. I battle a bit to understand your example. I therefore simplified your example further to assuming you have a `SalaryRange` for which the `Role` and `Location` need to be unique. I think if you understand the general idea you will be able to modified it to fit your example exactly.

We have the classes `Location` and `Role` as you defined it.

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="Location"/>
<owl:Class rdf:about="Role"/>
```

Then I defined object properties `role` and `location` follows:

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="location">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="SalaryRange"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="Location"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="role">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="SalaryRange"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="Role"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

Then to ensure that `SalaryRange` will have unique roles and locations, you can enforce it as follows:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="SalaryRange">
    <owl:hasKey rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="location"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="role"/>
    </owl:hasKey>
</owl:Class>
```

You can test this with the following individuals:

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="location1">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="location2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="location2"/>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="role1">
    <owl:sameAs rdf:resource="role2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="role2"/>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="salaryRange1">
    <location rdf:resource="location1"/>
    <role rdf:resource="role1"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="salaryRange2">
    <location rdf:resource="location2"/>
    <role rdf:resource="role2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

With these individuals a reasoner like Hermit will infer that `salaryRange1` and `salaryRange2` are the same individual. However, if you state that `salaryRange1` and `salaryRange2` are **different** individuals, you will get an inconsistency.

```
<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#AllDifferent"/>
    <owl:distinctMembers rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="salaryRange1"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="salaryRange2"/>
    </owl:distinctMembers>
</rdf:Description>
```

To resolve the inconsistency you can state that either `role1` and `role2` are different individuals OR `location1` and `location2` are different individuals.